# Bending an object into a circle

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I wanted to create a ring around my planet. Unfortunately the bend tool does not work. It does not work when I type in the bend value (360) and the menu option is greyed out.

I downloaded earlier versions of Blender (all the way back to 2.67 when it was still called Warp) and it turns my mesh into an hourglass shape rather than creating a ring. Any solutions?

[image]

Comment: I removed the references to 'modifier' in your question as you are using the 'Bend' tool not a modifier.

Comment: Use the curve modifier with a circle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Bend** tool, which is a newer operator than **Warp**, and take Warp's shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd>, works a bit different from **Warp**. I think here you just need the old **Warp** tool. You can still find it in the menu.

[image]

Another way for bending objects is to use **Simple Deform** modifier. It will bend along the **Local Z** axis. You can also give it a try.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the *Curve Modifier*.

First, add a Circle, by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and then going Curve>Circle. Then select the object you want to convert to a ring, go to the Properties panel, and under the Modifiers tab, add a `Curve` modifier.

[image]

Select your Circle (default name "BezierCircle") under the `Object` field and select -Y for the deformation axis (I don't really understand how this works, so just try them all :P).

Comment: At first, the Curve modifier was not working, then I played with the scaling of the Bezier circle and found out that scaling the curve to the ring's radius was enlarging the ring mesh (way beyond the clipping distance of the camera). I remember when a planetary ring could be made by scaling a plane to length, and then pressing Shift + W. The devs made some changes under the hood. By all rights the bend tool should do the same thing  (I am not the only one having a problem with it based on what I seen at developer.blender.org). The curve modifier works, with some tweaking. Thanks! :)