# How do I create grooves which have a certain shape and follow a round edge?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]How do I create grooves which have a certain shape and follow a round edge? In this example I draw a handle of a coffee mug, and I want the yellow area of the handle to be scooped out of the cylindrical handle, while following the direction of the handle. I am in cycles render.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with a cylinder add a bevel modifier to create the basic shape:

[image]
[image]

Repeat that shape with an array modifier.

[image]

On the same place as your object (it is important that the origins of both objects are in the same place). Add a bézier curve.

[image][image]

Edit the curve so it has the shape you want for the handle.

[image]

Now select the Cylinder and add a curve modifier to the modifiers stack. Select your curve as curve object, select the axis in which you want the deformation (in this case is the Z axis). You might need to adjust the count number on the array modifier or you may need to slide the object along the curve on the z axis for the object to fit properly.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The beauty of using modifiers is that you can keep editing the shape of the curve or the array that forms the handle. The changes will not be permanent until you apply the modifiers.

Comment: Another way to do this is using the **Bend** tool: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18767/1853 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21766/1853

Comment: Thanks for the help, is there anyway i can scoop out some of the top of the handle ? to make room for the thumb to lay in, im doing a design project. It is kind of hard to explain but I mean to do some curved extrusion